# Which font-family was used in this arxiv-paper?

Tags: fonts, latex

I was not able to find the font-family used in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.00015.pdf.

Is it a default font or an external one?

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com allows font identification question to some extent -- make sure to read the FAQ first and show the required research

Comment: That being said, the sources are available on arxiv, you could just take a look into the tex code ... https://arxiv.org/format/2204.00015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sources of the article are available on arxiv, so you could simply check the .tex file which essentially boils down to

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{newpxtext}

\begin{document}
In the era of Noisy Intermediate Scale Quantum Computers
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I actually was not aware that sources are available for download.